# How to pass an array of struct as an argument in Etherscan

Tags: arrays, parameters, tuples, solidity, etherscan

```
struct PricingOption {
   uint208 price;
   uint40 numberOfEntries;
}
```

`pricingOptions` is of type `PricingOption[]`. Trying to pass `pricingOptions` array as `[[1000000000000,10],[1700000000000,20]]` doesn't work. Wrapping numbers into quotes doesn't help neither. The way I pass param works in Remix, but doesn't work in Etherscan. Ho do I pass an array of struct in Etherscan?

```
invalid tuple value (argument="tuple", value="[100000000", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.0.7)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible. I had to use Remix.